# Javascript prompt alert and submit form with value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to submit the form using javascript when clicking on a image. Clicking the actual submit button works, but not the javascript submit.

```
<img class='File' src="imagehere" onclick="editFileName()"/>

<script>
        function editFileName() {
            var fileName = prompt("Type in name:");
            if (fileName != null) {
                document.getElementById('editNameField').value = fileName;

    //tried these two
                document.EditFileName.submit();
                document.getElementById('test').submit();
            }
        }
    </script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("EditUploadedFileName", "Folder", new { name = "EditFileName", id = "test" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" id="editNameField" value="a">
    <input type="hidden" id="blobName" value="a">
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

Edit

Corrected the button typo. It has nothing to do with this not working, was a typo when I inserted the code. Any reason for downvoting? Geez

Comment: i think wrong syntax `<button type="submit"</button>`

Comment: Yeah typo when I inserted the code here. But as I said the submit button works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with a working but not so good looking solution..

```
<script>
    function editFileName() {
        var fileName = prompt("Type in name");
        if (fileName != null) {
            document.getElementById('editFileName').value = fileName;
            document.getElementById("SubmitEdit").click();
        }
    }
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("EditUploadedFileName", "Folder", new { blobName = file.BlobName }))
{
<input type="hidden" name="editFileName" id="editFileName" />
<input type="submit" id="SubmitEdit" style="display:none;" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="submit"/>`
Change the button to an input and it should work.

Comment: I tried that aswell. 

It registers the prompt alert, but not             document.EditFileNameSubmit.submit(); or
            document.getElementById('test').submit();
I also tried with an alert after the prompt window and that works

Comment: Try changing the id from 'test' to something else, i've experienced problems in other languages using test as any kind of variable, a long shot but it might work. However the best thing you can do is open up Chrome developer tools and debug the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.forms["test"].submit();
```

Comment: Didn't work.. Tried document.forms["EditFileNameSubmit"].submit(); aswell

Comment: How does editFileName function get called. Is image inside form

Comment: Move image tag inside form

Comment: Move script below html it is recommended. there may be some other code on your page that is messing with this code